# get all objects from storage.local, sort them, create elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I do a http request to get a JSON, parse it and save the data in chrome.storage.local. When the user clicks the extension button a new tab opens and elements are populated with data from local storage (TR elements in a table). This works.

However, I would like to for the elements to be in a specific order based on one of the values (and maybe in the future let the user sort it by what the user wants).

Currently I'm looping through all the keys when creating the elements:

```
storage.get(null, function(items) {
    var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
    allKeys.forEach(function(key) {
        var result = /(?:^\d+$|kek)/.test(key);
        if (result) {
            //create appropriate elements;
        }
    });
});
```

I guess the solution should be something along the lines of get all the objects into an array, sort the array and then do a loop creating elements?

If that is the optimal way to go, [I found a good enough explanation of how to sort such array](https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/), however what I wasn't able to find is how to get all the objects from chrome.storage.local into an array.

EDIT: data saved in the storage looks like this:

```
44: // this is the key
csURL: "https://www.randomurl.com"
nURL: "http://www.randomurl2.com"
r: "82" // this is what I want all the objects sorted by
rc: "3079"
t: "stuff"
y: "1234"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: There's a lot of info in the question which seems extraneous and the only problem seems to be with sorting, right? To get help you should show an example and/or structure of the data.

Comment: `storage.set("allMyStuff", /* */);` -> `storage.get("allMyStuff")`

Comment: storage.get(null, function(items) {
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  
  if (a.field1 < b.field1) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.field1 > b.field1) {
    return 1;
  }

  
  return 0;
});
});

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated the post with sample storage entry.

Comment: @LDS thanks for the example, however I get `items.sort is not a function` error.

Comment: `var sorted = allKeys.sort((a, b) => items[a].r - items[b].r).map(k => items[k])`

Comment: @wOxxOm that did it! Thank you very much!

Comment: hey @Seminko if items is a object and not a array that may happens